# Expected value of $\sin(x)$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I have a uniformly distributed random variable $ \omega $ in the range $[\frac\pi2, \frac\pi{-2}]$. Then I have the function $ s = \sin(\omega) $  I want to calculate the expected value of this function $ s $.

So far I know that the uniformly distributed random variable can be written as $$ \omega = \frac1{\frac\pi2 - - \frac\pi2} = \frac 1\pi $$

Then I don't know if the correct way of calculating the expected value is $$ E = \int_{-\frac\pi2}^{\frac\pi2} \frac1\pi \sin(x) dx $$
or if I'm completely off.

Comment: By antisymmetry, $0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working seems fine.

And by the fact that sine is an odd function and $\omega$ is uniformly distributed symmetrically about $0$, the integral is evaluated to be $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The expected value of any random variable $s(\omega)$ where $\omega$ is having the probability distribution function $f(\omega)$ is given by:

**$$ E(s(\omega)) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} s(\omega)f(\omega)d\omega$$**
since $\omega$ is distributed uniformly in the interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ we have **$$f(\omega) = \frac{1}{(\pi/2-(-\pi/2))} = \frac{1}{\pi}$$**
Now, **$$E(s(\omega))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(\omega)f(\omega)d\omega$$**
or, **$$E(s(\omega))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sin(\omega)\frac{1}{\pi}d\omega$$**
The limits for $\omega$ is from $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ so the integral is 
**$$E(s(\omega))=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \sin(\omega)\frac{1}{\pi}d\omega$$**
The answer of this integral is $0$